# Grouped barplot using R barplot function

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am using the following code to get grouped barplot using R barplot function.

```
> df <- read.csv2(text = "x;y;z
  A;40;11
  B;66;16
  C;27;13
  D;10;42")
> bp <- barplot(t(df[ , -1]), beside=T, names=df$x)
```

but this is not working when my data has decimals. Like I can't get a barplot if my data is like:

```
> df <- read.csv2(text = "x;y;z
  A;40.9;11
  B;66;16
  C;27;13
  D;10;42")
```

Is there a way to modify this code to get plots for the decimal values as well? I want to use R barplot function, rather than going into some R package.

Thank you

Comment: make sure that the columns you transpose are numeric. in your example, `y` is a character, so if you fix that, it should work

Comment: I didn't get it. Would you please elaborate a little? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `type.convert` to convert the character type of data to numeric.

```
barplot(type.convert(t(df[-1])), beside = TRUE, names=df$x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. However, the fill option is not working to define color of the bars, with this method. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: You can specify color using `col` argument. Try `barplot(type.convert(t(df[-1])), beside = TRUE, names=df$x, col = c('red', 'green'))`

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma rather than a dot in your df:

```
> df <- read.csv2(text = "x;y;z
  A;40,9;11
  B;66;16
  C;27;13
  D;10;42")
```